# Using %{buildroot} in a SPEC file

Tags: uninstallation, rpmbuild, specifications

I'm creating a simple RPM installer, I just have to copy files to a directory structure I create in the `%install` process.

The `%install` process is fine, I create the following folder `/opt/company/application/` with the command `mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt/company/%{name}` and then I proceed to copy the files and subdirectories from my package. I've tried to install it and it works.

The doubt I have comes when uninstalling. I want to remove the folder `/opt/company/application/` and I thought you're supposed to use `%{buildroot}` anywhere when referencing the install location. Because my understanding is the user might have a different structure and you can't assume that `rmdir /opt/company/%{name}/` will work. Using that command in the `%postun` section deletes succesfully the directories whereas using `rmdir ${buildroot}/opt/company/%{name}` doesn't delete the folders.

My question is, shouldn't you be using `${buildroot}` in the `%postun` in order to get the proper install location? If that's not the case, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about it. If you claim the directory as your own in the `%files` section, RPM will handle it for you.

FYI, `%{buildroot}` probably won't exist on the target machine.

Comment: Well, yes, I'm claiming that directory as my own in the `%files` section. So then, whatever I write in the `%files` section is what I would need to use in the `%postun` section (if this is required), isn't it? And you're right, `%{buildroot}` shouldn't exist on the target machine.

Comment: By default you don't need `%postun` - RPM will delete any file you claim under `%files` automatically.